# problem with scraping websites with multiple pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using python 3.8 and scrapy 1.6, I wrote a spider to scrape a non-English website but pagination didn't work and I got a CSV file containing just page one's elements. As I couldn't find out the solution from other similar questions, I'm asking for help.

Here is my spider code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import logging
import urllib.parse
parts= urllib.parse.urlsplit(u'http://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/صفحهٔ_اصلی')
parts= parts._replace(path=urllib.parse.quote(parts.path.encode('utf8')))
encoded_url= parts.geturl().encode('ascii')
'https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D9%87%D9%94_%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%84%DB%8C'


class PromotionsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name= 'promotions'
    allowed_domains=['www.digikala.com']
    
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url= 'https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4',
            callback= self.parse, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36'})

    def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.xpath("//ul[@class='c-listing__items']/li"):
            yield{
                'title':product.xpath(".//a[@class='js-product-url']/text()").get(),
                'star':product.xpath(".//div[@class='c-product-box__engagement-rating']/text()").get(),
                'discounted_percent':product.xpath(".//div[@class='c-price__discount-oval']/span/text()").get(),
                'discounted_price':product.xpath(".//div[@class='c-price__value-wrapper']/text()").get(),
                'original_price':product.xpath(".//div[@class='c-price__value c-price__value--plp']/del/text()").get(),
                'url':response.urljoin(product.xpath(".//a[@class='js-product-url']/@href").get())
            }

        next_page=response.xpath("//a[@class='c-pager__next']/@href").get()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36'})
```

Using an absolute URL for the next page button plus response.follow or response.urljoin in last yield part didn't help either. I mean changing the last part of the code bellow didn't help either:

```
next_page=response.xpath("//html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/article/div/div[3]/ul/li[8]/a/@href").get()
if next_page:
    yield response.follow(url=next_page, callback=self.parse, headers={'User-Agent': 
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
        Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36'})
```

Can someone help me out with the pagination problem?

Thank you!!

By the way, this is the log I got after running the code in Answer 1:

```
2020-08-19 08:35:29 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.6.0 started (bot: digikala)
2020-08-19 08:35:29 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.8.5 (default, Aug  5 2020, 09:44:06) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 2.9.2, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
2020-08-19 08:35:29 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'digikala', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'FEED_URI': 'dataset1.csv', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'digikala.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['digikala.spiders']}
2020-08-19 08:35:29 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 7e28ac39aab69aaa
2020-08-19 08:35:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-08-19 08:35:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-08-19 08:35:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-08-19 08:35:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-08-19 08:35:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-08-19 08:35:29 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-08-19 08:35:29 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-08-19 08:35:32 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.digikala.com/robots.txt> (failed 1 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2020-08-19 08:35:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.digikala.com/robots.txt> (failed 2 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2020-08-19 08:35:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET https://www.digikala.com/robots.txt> (failed 3 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2020-08-19 08:35:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (500) <GET https://www.digikala.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-08-19 08:35:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4> (referer: None)
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب تختخوابت را مرتب کن اثر ژنرال ویلیام اچ. مک ریون', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۴\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': '\n                                    ٪۱۰\n                                         ', 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۱۳,۵۰۰ ', 'original_price': '۱۵,۰۰۰', 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-392946/کتاب-تختخوابت-را-مرتب-کن-اثر-ژنرال-ویلیام-اچ-مک-ریون'}
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب خودت را به فنا نده اثر گری جان بیشاپ', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۴\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': '\n                                    ٪۲۹\n                                         ', 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۱۲,۷۰۰ ', 'original_price': '۱۸,۰۰۰', 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-1050124/کتاب-خودت-را-به-فنا-نده-اثر-گری-جان-بیشاپ'}
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب قانون 5 ثانیه اثر مل رابینز نشر نوین', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۴\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۳۵,۰۰۰ ', 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-1505778/%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%88%D9%86-5-%D8%AB%D8%A7%D9%86%DB%8C%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%AB%D8%B1-%D9%85%D9%84-%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%B2-%D9%86%D8%B4%D8%B1-%D9%86%D9%88%DB%8C%D9%86?variant_id=3853061&ads_cookie=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0eXBlIjoic3BvbnNvcmVkIiwiaWQiOjIzNTE4MCwidmFyaWFudF9pZCI6Mzg1MzA2MSwiZXhwaXJlX2F0IjoxNjAwNDg4MzMzfQ.1Mh5KnFzmaQyP-dW73x3Ik7xkdXaaYWyktov9XTE8rQ&click_expire=1'}
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب ای کاش وقتی 20 ساله بودم می دانستم اثر تینا سیلیگ', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۵\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': '\n                                    ٪۱۵\n                                         ', 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۲۹,۰۰۰ ', 'original_price': '۳۴,۰۰۰', 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-222291/کتاب-ای-کاش-وقتی-20-ساله-بودم-می-دانستم-اثر-تینا-سیلیگ'}
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب چهار اثر از فلورانس اسکاول شین\xa0اثر فلورانس اسکاول شین نشر پیکان', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۵\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': '\n                                    ٪۲۵\n                                         ', 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۴۸,۹۰۰ ', 'original_price': '۶۵,۰۰۰', 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-2696368/کتاب-چهار-اثر-از-فلورانس-اسکاول-شین-اثر-فلورانس-اسکاول-شین-نشر-پیکان'}
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب شرمنده نباش دختر اثر ریچل هالیس نشر کتاب کوله پشتی', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۶\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۳۰,۰۰۰ ', 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-1556940/کتاب-شرمنده-نباش-دختر-اثر-ریچل-هالیس-نشر-کتاب-کوله-پشتی'}
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب هنر شفاف اندیشیدن اثر رولف دوبلی', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۴\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': '\n                                    ٪۱۰\n                                         ', 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۵۸,۴۰۰ ', 'original_price': '۶۵,۰۰۰', 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-82937/کتاب-هنر-شفاف-اندیشیدن-اثر-رولف-دوبلی'}
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب زنان زیرک اثر شری آرگو', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۵\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۳۳,۰۰۰ ', 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-413298/کتاب-زنان-زیرک-اثر-شری-آرگو'}
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب قانون جذب اثر راندا برن نشر نیک فرجام', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۵\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': '\n                                    ٪۶۰\n                                         ', 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۱۸,۰۸۰ ', 'original_price': '۴۵,۰۰۰', 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-1598779/کتاب-قانون-جذب-اثر-راندا-برن-نشر-نیک-فرجام'}
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب نیمه تاریک وجود اثر دبی فورد نشر آتیسا', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۵\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': '\n                                    ٪۵۹\n                                         ', 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۱۸,۹۰۰ ', 'original_price': '۴۶,۰۰۰', 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-1111023/کتاب-نیمه-تاریک-وجود-اثر-دبی-فورد-نشر-آتیسا'}
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب کاش وقتی بیست ساله بودم می دانستم اثر تینا سیلیگ نشر میلکان', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۴\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': '\n                                    ٪۲۲\n                                         ', 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۲۷,۲۶۰ ', 'original_price': '۳۵,۰۰۰', 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-2163319/کتاب-کاش-وقتی-بیست-ساله-بودم-می-دانستم-اثر-تینا-سیلیگ-نشر-میلکان'}
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب حکایت دولت و فرزانگی اثر مارک فیشر', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۶\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۱۵,۰۰۰ ', 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-174855/کتاب-حکایت-دولت-و-فرزانگی-اثر-مارک-فیشر'}
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب از حال بد به حال خوب اثر دیوید برنز', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۴\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۹۰,۰۰۰ ', 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-211336/کتاب-از-حال-بد-به-حال-خوب-اثر-دیوید-برنز'}
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب پدر پولدار، پدر بی پول اثر رابرت کیوساکی', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۵\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': '\n                                    ٪۲۵\n                                         ', 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۳۶,۰۰۰ ', 'original_price': '۴۸,۰۰۰', 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-38248/کتاب-پدر-پولدار-پدر-بی-پول-اثر-رابرت-کیوساکی'}
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب برتری خفیف اثر جف اولسون', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۵\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': '\n                                    ٪۱۳\n                                         ', 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۳۹,۱۰۰ ', 'original_price': '۴۵,۰۰۰', 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-141776/کتاب-برتری-خفیف-اثر-جف-اولسون'}
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب اسرار ذهن ثروتمند اثر تی. هارو اکر', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۶\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۳۹,۹۰۰ ', 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-38199/کتاب-اسرار-ذهن-ثروتمند-اثر-تی-هارو-اکر'}
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب عیبی ندارد اگر حالت خوش نیست اثر مگان دیواین نشر میلکان', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۶\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۳۵,۰۰۰ ', 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-2295613/کتاب-عیبی-ندارد-اگر-حالت-خوش-نیست-اثر-مگان-دیواین-نشر-میلکان'}
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب به بچه ها گفتن، از بچه ها شنیدن 1 (گفت و شنود با کودکان)', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۴\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۵۵,۰۰۰ ', 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-40926/کتاب-به-بچه-ها-گفتن-از-بچه-ها-شنیدن-1-گفت-و-شنود-با-کودکان'}
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب تحلیل رفتار متقابل اثر اریک برن', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۲\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۶۵,۰۰۰ ', 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-191367/کتاب-تحلیل-رفتار-متقابل-اثر-اریک-برن'}
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب پاکسازی ضمیر اثر دبی فورد انتشارات آتیسا', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۳\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': '\n                                    ٪۶۵\n                                         ', 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۱۶,۲۶۰ ', 'original_price': '۴۶,۰۰۰', 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-1647566/کتاب-پاکسازی-ضمیر-اثر-دبی-فورد-انتشارات-آتیسا'}
2020-08-19 08:35:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4>
{'title': 'کتاب فلسفه تنهایی اثر لارس اسونسن نشر نو', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۳\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': '\n                                    ۳۵,۰۰۰ ', 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-1109645/کتاب-فلسفه-تنهایی-اثر-لارس-اسونسن-نشر-نو'}
2020-08-19 08:35:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type%5B0%5D=4844&promotion_types%5B0%5D=promotion&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4&pageno=62> (referer: https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type[0]=4844&promotion_types[0]=promotion&pageno=1&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4)
2020-08-19 08:35:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type%5B0%5D=4844&promotion_types%5B0%5D=promotion&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4&pageno=62>
{'title': 'کتاب ماساژ آیورودیک اثر هریش جوهری انتشارات سفیر اردهال', 'star': None, 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': None, 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-2957437/کتاب-ماساژ-آیورودیک-اثر-هریش-جوهری-انتشارات-سفیر-اردهال'}
2020-08-19 08:35:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type%5B0%5D=4844&promotion_types%5B0%5D=promotion&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4&pageno=62>
{'title': 'کتاب انسان های موفق چگونه می اندیشند اثر جان سی مکس ول', 'star': None, 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': None, 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-178649/کتاب-انسان-های-موفق-چگونه-می-اندیشند-اثر-جان-سی-مکس-ول'}
2020-08-19 08:35:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type%5B0%5D=4844&promotion_types%5B0%5D=promotion&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4&pageno=62>
{'title': 'کتاب سمینار تصویری آموزشی اثر برایان تریسی', 'star': None, 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': None, 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-242658/کتاب-سمینار-تصویری-آموزشی-اثر-برایان-تریسی'}
2020-08-19 08:35:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type%5B0%5D=4844&promotion_types%5B0%5D=promotion&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4&pageno=62>
{'title': 'کتاب تا نغمه ای در دل دارید باید زنده بمانید اثر سرنا دایر،وین دایر', 'star': None, 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': None, 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-247582/کتاب-تا-نغمه-ای-در-دل-دارید-باید-زنده-بمانید-اثر-سرنا-دایروین-دایر'}
2020-08-19 08:35:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type%5B0%5D=4844&promotion_types%5B0%5D=promotion&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4&pageno=62>
{'title': 'کتاب اینترنت با مغز ما چه می کند اثر نیکلاس کار', 'star': '\n                            ۴.۳\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': None, 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-143243/کتاب-اینترنت-با-مغز-ما-چه-می-کند-اثر-نیکلاس-کار'}
2020-08-19 08:35:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type%5B0%5D=4844&promotion_types%5B0%5D=promotion&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4&pageno=62>
{'title': 'کتاب به چشمک های خداوند توجه کن اثر اسکوایر راشنل', 'star': '\n                            ۵\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': None, 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-271643/کتاب-به-چشمک-های-خداوند-توجه-کن-اثر-اسکوایر-راشنل'}
2020-08-19 08:35:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type%5B0%5D=4844&promotion_types%5B0%5D=promotion&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4&pageno=62>
{'title': 'کتاب گانگ هو، مدیریت شگفت انگیز اثر کنت بلانچارد\xa0نشر نسل نواندیش', 'star': None, 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': None, 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-41160/کتاب-گانگ-هو-مدیریت-شگفت-انگیز-اثر-کنت-بلانچارد-نشر-نسل-نواندیش'}
2020-08-19 08:35:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type%5B0%5D=4844&promotion_types%5B0%5D=promotion&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4&pageno=62>
{'title': 'کتاب راز شادابی کودکان اثر استیو بیدالف', 'star': '\n                            ۳\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': None, 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-71210/کتاب-راز-شادابی-کودکان-اثر-استیو-بیدالف'}
2020-08-19 08:35:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type%5B0%5D=4844&promotion_types%5B0%5D=promotion&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4&pageno=62>
{'title': 'کتاب زندگی مثبت اثر کارن ریویچ،اندرو شاته', 'star': None, 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': None, 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-242600/کتاب-زندگی-مثبت-اثر-کارن-ریویچاندرو-شاته'}
2020-08-19 08:35:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type%5B0%5D=4844&promotion_types%5B0%5D=promotion&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4&pageno=62>
{'title': 'کتاب آموزش محبت آمیز کودکان اثر دکتر مارشال روزنبرگ', 'star': '\n                            ۴\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': None, 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-345552/کتاب-آموزش-محبت-آمیز-کودکان-اثر-دکتر-مارشال-روزنبرگ'}
2020-08-19 08:35:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type%5B0%5D=4844&promotion_types%5B0%5D=promotion&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4&pageno=62>
{'title': 'کتاب آینده خود را خلق کنید اثر برایان تریسی', 'star': '\n                            ۴\n                            ', 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': None, 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-38192/کتاب-آینده-خود-را-خلق-کنید-اثر-برایان-تریسی'}
2020-08-19 08:35:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type%5B0%5D=4844&promotion_types%5B0%5D=promotion&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4&pageno=62>
{'title': 'کتاب پیام تن اثر ترز برترا و کارول برنشتاین نشر آسیم', 'star': None, 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': None, 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-2329294/کتاب-پیام-تن-اثر-ترز-برترا-و-کارول-برنشتاین-نشر-آسیم'}
2020-08-19 08:35:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.digikala.com/search/category-book/?type%5B0%5D=4844&promotion_types%5B0%5D=promotion&last_filter=type&last_value=4844&sortby=4&pageno=62>
{'title': 'کتاب قدرت همزمانی اثر دیوید ریکو نشر افکار', 'star': None, 'discounted_percent': None, 'discounted_price': None, 'original_price': None, 'url': 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-2270633/کتاب-قدرت-همزمانی-اثر-دیوید-ریکو-نشر-افکار'}
2020-08-19 08:35:36 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-08-19 08:35:36 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored csv feed (54 items) in: dataset1.csv
2020-08-19 08:35:36 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1829,
 'downloader/request_count': 5,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 5,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 173357,
 'downloader/response_count': 5,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/500': 3,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 19, 4, 5, 36, 263555),
 'item_scraped_count': 54,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 60,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'retry/count': 2,
 'retry/max_reached': 1,
 'retry/reason_count/500 Internal Server Error': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/500': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 19, 4, 5, 29, 409327)}
2020-08-19 08:35:36 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

The point is the 'item_scraped_count' should be around 2000 items but it is still 54

Answer (score 1):

Can you try it like this?

```
next_page=response.xpath("//a[@class='c-pager__next']/@href").get()
if next_page:
    yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36'})
```

The xpath in your second piece of code doesn't give any results for me, so it makes sense that doesn't work.
It would also be useful if you could share the logs so we can see if there is anything else going wrong.

EDIT:
The xpath above will get you the link to go to the last page. To go to the next page, you can use this one:

```
next_page = response.xpath('//*[@class="c-pager__item is-active"]/../following-sibling::*//@href').extract_first()
```

Comment: Hey @Wim Hermans, thanks for your help, I added the log I got to the post. It still doesn't scrape other pages.

Comment: I see now that when I disable javascript and click on the next button, it jumps to the last page. That's why scrapes only 54 elements. Unless you click on page numbers from page one to 62 in this case. So, how can I tell scrapy to click on page numbers instead of the next button?

Comment: We just have to adapt the xpath then. I made an edit to the answer with the correct xpath for the next page (I think)

Comment: Thank you @Wim Hermans, now I got 108 item-scraped which means it scraped 3 pages, but there are 62 pages to be scraped. what do you think the problem is?

Comment: probably the xpath isn't precise enough - in this case when we go to page 2, the xpath that should give the next page might refer back to page 1 instead. I edited the xpath again to take the url that comes after the 'active' one

Comment: Oh @Wim Hermans, I'm so thankful!!! You were right and it worked!!!!:))